# Не дает ввести в консоли имя,ну и не выводит его,знаю где ошибка но исправить не получается

Tags: c

в строчках 2-5 у char нужна одна * так же ошибка в 6-9,но где не понимаю

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


2 struct Student {
3 int* date;
4 int* bit;
 5 char** name;
};

int main() {
6 struct Student st;
int N;
printf("Введите количество студентов ");
scanf("%d",&N);

7 st.date = (int*)malloc((N) * sizeof(int*));
8 st.bit = (int*)malloc((N) * sizeof(int*));
9 st.name = (char**)malloc((N) * sizeof(char**));

for(int i = 0;i != N;i++)
st.name[i] = (char*)malloc((256) * sizeof(char*));

int a = 0;
int* correct = (int*)malloc((N) * sizeof(int*));

for(int i = 0;i != N;i++){
printf("Введите данные студента №%d в порядке: Учебный год, Имя, количество биткоинов на счёте\n",i+1);
scanf("%d", &st.date[i]);
if(st.date[i] >= 2022)
{
correct[a] = i;
a++;
}
for(int j = 0;st.name[0][j]!= '\0';j++)
scanf("%c", &st.name[i][j]);
printf("АААА%s",st.name[i]);
printf("ББББ");
scanf("%d", &st.bit[i]);
printf("click");
}
printf("\n\n\nСтуденты 2022 года и позже\n");
for(int i = 0;i != a;i++)
{
printf("Имя:%s\nУчебный год:%d\nКол-во биткоинов на счёте:%d\n\n",&st.name[0][correct[i]], 
st.date[correct[i]],st.bit[correct[i]]);
}
}
```

Comment: Вы выделяете место для массива целых, а размер берете для указателя на целое. Аналогично с символом. Там, как понимаю, строка предполагается, то есть массив символов. Тогда в строке 5 ```char*```, в строке 9 - преобразование к нему же, и размер брать от ```char```

Comment: мне говорят сделать  наоборот массив структур,это верно либо нет?

Comment: я в этом не совссем разбираюсь,а преподавателю сдать нужно,понимаю что нужно двойной указатель убрать,но тогда все рушиться

Comment: Во-первых, Вам действительно нужен массив структур. Во-вторых, что Вы пытаетесь сделать, например, вот здесь: ```st.name[i] = (char*)malloc((256) * sizeof(char*));``` ? В-третьих, если не разбирайтесь, то начинайте изучать и разбираться. Разобраться Вам здесь помогут, но делать за Вас вряд ли кто-то захочет.